# Using OfficeDev/generator-office to create Excel TaskPane React Add-in seems to be missing a devDependency for postcss

Tags: ms-office

I tried using **yo office** to create a new Excel TaskPane React Add-In. I'm using the (ironically Microsoft) **rush** tool to build a monorepo. It's quite picky about dependencies. It gives errors about how **postcss-loader** requires a peer dependency of **postcess** but none is present. Sure enough, the generated package.json file has a devDependency for postcss-loader but not postcss. Trying it with ordinary npm it appears that css-loader is dragging in postcsss and saving the day. I'm pretty new to all of this but it seems likely an explicit dependency is called for.